# A session that is created in a route is not available in other routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I'm trying to set up sessions in my node.js app. In order to do that I'm using the modules "express","express-session" and "express-mysql-session" to store them in a database on my server. My code works absolutely fine as long as I'm only accessing the req.session parameters inside the route the session is created. In other routes (or even the startup file) the created parameters throw an undefined error.

I've already tried to create the app.use(session(...)) in the startup file. If I do that everything works fine and the parameters that are created in some route are also usable in other routes. But since I want to keep the startup file as small as possible these lines of code should be handled in a route.

Here is my code: 
login.js (a route)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var session = require('express-session');
var MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session');

var dbOptions = {
    host: "ip",
    user: "user",
    password: "pw",
    database: "some db"
};

var sessionStore = MySQLStore(dbOptions);

router.use(session({
    key: 'some key',
    secret: 'some secret',
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

router.post('/login', (req, res) =>{
    req.session.username = req.body.username;
    res.end("done");
});

router.get('/sessionTest', (req, res) => {
    if(req.session.username) {
        res.write(`<h1>Hello ${req.session.username} </h1><br>`);
        res.end('<a href='+'/timetracking/logout'+'>Logout</a>');
    }
    else {
        res.write('<h1>Please login first.</h1>');
        res.end('<a href='+'/timetracking/login'+'>Login</a>');
    }
});

router.get('/logout',(req,res) => {
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        res.redirect('/timetracking/login');
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

timetracking.js (the startup file)

```
var http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var gets = require('./lib/gets');
var login = require('./lib/login');
const session = require('express-session');


//Make '/timetracking/' to the standard handler for get requests
app.use('/timetracking', [gets, login]);

app.get('/test', (req, res) =>{
    res.send(req.session.username);
});

app.listen(80);
```

When I'm loading localhost/test I can still see the cookie in the web developer tools. But "req.session.username" is undefined.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `req.session` will only be available in routes that occur AFTER the session middleware executes (order dependent).  And, if the session middleware is only on one router, then that `req.session` will only be available in routes that that match that router and only after that router runs on a given request.  So, if you want `req.session` valid across all your routes, the middleware needs to be defined early and in a way that the middleware runs on all possible routes (that you want to use it on), not only in some routers that only run on some paths.

Comment: Remember, it is your session middleware that sets `req.session` on any given incoming request.  It has to run on a given request before you want to access `req.session`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok thank you. That's what I expected to be the case. So for now I will define my sessions in the startup file of my App. I just hoped that there would be a better solution, so my startup file could be as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.session` will only be available in routes that occur AFTER the session middleware executes (order dependent). And, if the session middleware is only on one router, then that `req.session` will only be available in routes that that match that router and only after that router runs on a given request.

So, if you want `req.session` valid across all your routes, the middleware needs to be defined early and in a way that the middleware runs on all possible routes (that you want to use it on), not only in some routers that only run on some paths.

Remember, it is your session middleware that sets `req.session` on any given incoming request. It has to run on a given request before you want to access `req.session`.

You don't have to put your session middleware into your startup file directly.  You can still put it in its own module, you just have to load that module from the startup file and pass it the `app` object so it can initialize the global middleware before any of your routes.

Here's an example startup file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// initialize global middleware
require('./myMiddleware')(app);

// set up other routers and routes here
// and start the server
```

And, a myMiddlware.js file:

```
// load and initialize session stuff
const session = ....;

module.exports = function(app) {
    // install session middleware
    app.use(session(...))
}
```